# Vlookup is returning blank cells where there should be values displaying

Tags: excel, vlookup

Currently trying to reference two sheets in the same workbook to display the category of a product alongside the name of the product for instance I want to cross reference a piece of pipe so that the title and categories show up together.

I have been using the following formula

```
=vlookup(A:A,Sheet1!A:F,5,false)
=vlookup(A:A,Sheet1!A:F,6,false)
```

The formula to pull the 5th column returns the correct values, but the formula for the 6th is inconsistent and is often showing blank cells where there are actually values that should be displaying

I did another vlookup on the second sheet to pull in titles instead and that worked properly.

Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Screenshot or sample data?

Comment: So I while I was working to get a screenshot, I realized the issue. Somehow there are duplicate records. One set had the value, the second did not. The vlookup was returning the value from the first instance of it.

Comment: ^ Yes this is what vlookup does.